# Time complexity of function call

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

what would be the complexity of such program?
Code:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
{  
   g(n);  //any function call
}
```

Comment: It completely depends on what `g` is.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: Your question is a very basic one. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) which cover some fundamentals you seem to be missing in detail. Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific problems you encountered. Good luck!

Comment: _If_ $g(n)$ is a function (same result/side effects every time called with identical parameters), it is higher than seems warranted.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $g$ doesn't have any side effects, the complexity of this program is (up to constants) $n$ times the complexity of $g(n)$.

If $g$ does have side effects, then the time complexity of $g$ isn't well-defined. However, if the time complexity $T_g$ of $g$ satisfies $T_g(n) = O(G(n))$, then your code is $O(nG(n))$, and similarly if $T_g(n) = \Omega(G(n))$ then your code is $\Omega(n(G(n))$.

Comment: Only if `g(n)`'s running time does not depend on the value of `n`. Usually, it does.

Comment: @reinierpost Yes, I am taking this into account.

Comment: What if the running time of $g(n)$ is $O(2^n)$? Then the running time of the program is also $O(2^n)$, not only $O(n2^n)$. I am referring to your first sentence.

Comment: @wythagoras No, that's actually false. The code calls $g(n)$, not $g(i)$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus You are right, never mind.

Comment: Is that intentional or a typo?

Comment: @reinierpost How would I know? I answered the question as stated.